# Grid or TextGrid constant width cells

Tags: graphics, text-formatting, grid-layouts

I am having problems with white spaces in lists displayed in Grid. The problem is that white spaces have less height and width compared to cells that contain text. I also tried none, None, None[], null, Null, Null[],nothing, Nothing. " " seems to be the only solution that is not visible. Spacings->{2,2} seems to be relative not absolute. it only adds padding to what is already there. how can I define constant height and width for all cells? and is there a better way to describe white space other than string " "?

```
b={
{" "," ",38," "," "," "},
{" "," "," "," ",35," "},
{" ",19," "," "," "," "},
{" ",30," ",46," "," "},
{" "," "," "," "," "," "},
{" "," "," ",52," "," "}
};
Grid[b,Frame->All]
```

Answer (score 6):

Replace `" "` with  `Invisible[38]`:

```
Row[{Grid[b, Frame -> All], 
  Grid[b /. " " -> Invisible[38], Frame -> All]}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[{Grid[b, Frame -> All, Spacings -> {2, 2}], 
  Grid[b /. " " -> Invisible[38], Frame -> All, Spacings -> {2, 2}]}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use the option [`ItemSize`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItemSize.html):

```
Grid[b, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All, ItemSize -> {All, 1}]
```

[image]

or the option [`ColumnsEqual`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColumnsEqual.html):

```
Grid[b, Spacings -> {2, 2}, Frame -> All, ColumnsEqual -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Grid[b/. " " -> Invisible[10],Spacings->{2,2},Frame->All] works but
Grid[b/. " " -> Invisible[0],Spacings->{2,2},Frame->All] has problems

Comment: @acacia, added an example with the option `Spacings->{2,2}` .